# Pass XML document as parameter to sql script in .net vb

Tags: xml, vb.net, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, smo

How can I pass XML document as Parameter to SQL script in vb.net? I want to use the XML as a variable in SQL script. The SQL script dont recognizes the variable which i as a parameter submitter in .net

This is my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sqlSkript>
   <parameter>
      <name>name</name>
      <datentyp>varchar</datentyp>
   </parameter>
   <parameter>
      <name>strasse</name>
      <datentyp>varchar</datentyp>
   </parameter>
</sqlSkript>
```

This is my SQL-Script.

```
DECLARE @xml xml

SET @xml = @test

SELECT  t.name AS table_name,
        SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS schema_name,
        c.name AS column_name,
        st.name as datatyp

FROM    sys.tables AS t
        INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
        INNER JOIN sys.types st ON st.system_type_id = c.system_type_id 
        AND st.name != 'sysname'

WHERE   (c.name like '%' + (SELECT @xml.value('(/sqlSkript/parameter/name)[1]', 'varchar(100)')) + '%'
        AND st.name like (SELECT @xml.value('(/sqlSkript/parameter/datentyp)[1]', 'varchar(100)')))
        or
        (c.name like '%' + (SELECT @xml.value('(/sqlSkript/parameter/name)[2]', 'varchar(100)')) + '%'
        AND st.name like (SELECT @xml.value('(/sqlSkript/parameter/datentyp)[2]', 'varchar(100)')))

ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

This is my vb.net code

```
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()

        Dim xmldoc As New Xml.XmlDocument
        xmldoc.Load(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath & "\XML\indivudellParameter.xml"))

        Dim param As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@test", SqlDbType.Xml)
        param.Value = New SqlXml(New XmlTextReader(xmldoc.InnerXml, XmlNodeType.Document, Nothing))
        command.Parameters.Add(param)

        Using reader As SqlDataReader = _server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteReader(script, command)
            While reader.Read()
                //do something
            End While
            reader.Close()
        End Using
```

EDIT:

workaround

```
        Dim xmldoc As New Xml.XmlDocument
        xmldoc.Load(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Application.StartupPath & "\XML\indivudellParameter.xml"))

        script = script.Replace("@test", xmldoc.InnerXml)

        Using reader As SqlDataReader = _server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteReader(script)
            While reader.Read()
                  // do something
            End While
```

Comment: Which RDBMS (product and version)?

Comment: I use MS Sql Server 2008 r2

Comment: In this case you should start the SQL Profiler and check what command your SQL Server gets...

Comment: The SQL Profiler indicates that the variable isnt passed. Sql server returns 'The '@test' scalar variable must be declared.

Comment: Is this script running in SSMS correctly and giving the correct result?

Comment: Yes the Skript run when i do this:

Comment: SET @xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <sqlSkript>
    <parameter>
     <name>name</name>
     <datentyp>varchar</datentyp>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
     <name>strasse</name>
     <datentyp>varchar</datentyp>
    </parameter>
   </sqlSkript>';

Comment: Why not execute stored procedure from c# code.  It would be more efficient than using a c# SQL.  You can even assign parameters to the four returned values.

Comment: Because it is used in different databases. Then i must always first create the procedure befor i can run it. This not the way i will do it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Might be quite simple:

Are you sure that you want to compare your XML-data values against st.name in both cases (marked the places with `***`)?

```
WHERE   (c.name like '%' + (SELECT @xml.value('(/sqlSkript/parameter/name)[1]', 'varchar(100)')) + '%'
        AND ***st.name*** like (SELECT @xml.value('(/sqlSkript/parameter/datentyp)[1]', 'varchar(100)')))
        or
        (c.name like '%' + (SELECT @xml.value('(/sqlSkript/parameter/name)[2]', 'varchar(100)')) + '%'
        AND ***st.name*** like (SELECT @xml.value('(/sqlSkript/parameter/datentyp)[2]', 'varchar(100)')))
```

If it's not that simple: Try to check if your parameter comes into the SQL script correctly (write it into some temp table and check it there.

Comment: Yes because I compare different values.

Comment: Please give more information: What is your actual data like? Is the script working correctly if you set `@test` to your XML and executet this in SSMS? Did you check which command gets into SQL Server with the Profiler? Anyway: Better was a SQL Server inline TVF, taking the XML as parameter and returning your result set.

Comment: I use the script for analyze a database to check whether certain column exist. The xml contains my search parameter.

Comment: OK, now I understand what you want... I just checked it and it works correctly... Did you check the content of the `xmldoc`? is it filled correctly? "indivudellParameter.xml" sounds sweet, but might be a typo? You might try to pass your XML as string parameter, The conversion to XML is done implicitly...

Comment: I think i have  found the failure but dont know i can fix it. SqlCommand dont run with smo namespace in my code. When i try it with the sqlconnection namespace it works.

Comment: Where is there a namespace? Do you speak about a namespace in your XML?

Comment: No I mean the smo namespace which is implemented in the .net Framework. I use smo to log on to sql server in my .net code.

Comment: @battleboimatze I've never tried to pass XML from VB.Net to SQL Server. As your workaroud with the text replace seems to work I'd suggest to pass the `InnerXml` from your `xmldoc` directly as string parameter. Did you try this?

Comment: Yes it works with the connection object from ado.net but in my application i use every time smo. So i use the workaround. But thanks for the help.